# How to upload a file to Amazon S3 using an already made presigned-url through the command line interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Is it possible to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket using an already prepared presigned-url through the command line. If so, how do I do this?

Running `aws s3 cp <local_file> <presigned_url>` doesn't work. I can't find any documentation related to presigned urls on the internet, so I would imagine that this isn't possible, but I'm still hopeful.

Comment: You should not use the `aws` cli for that but instead just use e.g. `curl`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085141/2442804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload to s3 with curl using pre-signed URL (getting 403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067993/upload-to-s3-with-curl-using-pre-signed-url-getting-403)

Comment: The whole point of pre-signed URLs is so that you don't have to supply credentials. If you had credentials, you would be using the awscli (or a custom app that uses a credentialed AWS SDK). BTW that pre-signed URL includes the bucket and key so, assuming that you have local AWS credentials with the relevant permission, you could technically infer the bucket/key from the pre-signed URL and then upload using `aws s3 cp`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you already have the presigned url for put-object, just use curl:

```
curl "presignedurl" --upload-file yourfile.txt
```

I just tested and works great. For example:

```
curl "https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASDFLWKAS0F123&Signature=667S%22F%24%ASDasdfasdf%2Fasdfl&Expires=1634314495" --upload-file test.txt
```

In case you want to generate a presigned url, you can just check here for examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html